# Integration of a 3D function with constants

Tags: numerical-integration

I have the following (in simplified form) function (Theta, Phi, Si) with three constants (a, b, c). I want to integrate it to find the volume enclosed in terms of constants a, b and c.

```
f = Cos[Theta] (a Cos[Si]^2 Sin[Phi]^2+Sin[Si]^2 (a Cos[Theta]^2 Sin[Phi]^2+(b-2 c Sin[Phi]^2) Sin[Theta]^2)+Cos[Phi]^2 (a Cos[Si]^2+Sin[Si]^2 (a Cos[Theta]^2-2 c Sin[Theta]^2)))

g = Integrate[Sin[Theta]*f, {Phi, 0, 2 Pi}, {Theta, 0, Pi}, {Si, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

I tried it in two ways, but both have their own issues.

1. When I integrated it as it is, the result was "0" as the function bounds the same volume on positive and negative axes.
2. When I tried to integrate it with Abs[f], due to the presence of three unknown constants, it did not work.

Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the integral of the absolute value. I would start with a simpler example such as `Integrate[RealAbs[Cos[x]^2-a],{x,0,2*Pi},Assumptions->a>0]`. Looks simple, but the output is already too long for a comment.

Comment: Using `FullSimplify[f]` results in `Cos[Theta] (a Cos[Si]^2 + Sin[Si]^2 (a Cos[Theta]^2 + (b - 2 c) Sin[Theta]^2))` in which `Phi` disappears and you only really have 2 constants:  `a` and `b - 2 c`.

Comment: If your real function is more complicated than the example given, I suspect you're going to need to set values for `a` and `b - 2 c` and use `NIntegrate`.